# Key exists already but getting GPG error

Tags: apt, gnupg

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit desktop,and updating worked fine before, but suddenly it doesn't (it is a long time from last updating, so I can't ensure what operation leads this problem).

[image: "Software & Updates" shown key exists already]

As you can see, all keys exist already, but I still got a bunch of key missing errors, and I doubt it is a server error, so switched "download from" server, but no luck, then I tried to remove all keys manually and run:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com [key]
```

To add all keys in error message, but still get this error, why?